# Getting fields from duplicate record in MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, duplicates

When I insert a potential record into MySQL table, I'm getting a "duplicate record error" (error #1062 to be exact).

The table is called "Titles".
The description is:

```
+----------+------------+  
| Title_ID | Title_Name |  
+----------+------------+  
| integer  | text       |  
+----------+------------+
```

Here is my SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO Titles VALUES
(
    0,
    "Apple"
)
```

I have C++ class that models the table record:

```
struct Title_Record
{
    unsigned int title_id;
    std::string  title_name;
};
```

I'm looking for a "least work by the program" to retrieve the record that is the duplicate, so I can fill in the members of the `Title_Record` structure.

How do I go about locating the duplicate record?

Should I search first then append if not exists?

*Note: unlike a lot of StackOverflow posts, I'm not interested in deleting a duplicate record, but loading it from the database.*

**Environment:**
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017
MySQL 5.7.27 C API

I have the table set up to only accept unique records, based on the Title_Name field.

Comment: Which column is the unique key? Just do a `SELECT` query for that column with the value that you're trying to insert.

Comment: You could use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to replace the value if the record already exists.

Comment: The NAME key is the unique key.

Comment: I don't want to replace the value or change the record.  I want to copy the memory struct from the duplicate record, hopefully without searching the database (again).

Comment: There's no way to do it in one step. You could try the insert, and if you get a 1062 error you can do the SELECT query to get the duplicate.